# How to activate an android app with voice

Tags: java, android, assistant

I am trying to program an assistant like Siri Alexa etc. I want to activate the app while I say "ok Toby" or something like that. I am using Java Android. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check their Developers website and figure out how to create custom commands for your android application. And since its android Google provides a pretty good information about its assistant and custom calls. You might want to check this:

[Google Assistant Developers Website](https://developers.google.com/assistant/)

Comment: that's not what I meant, I have already codded the app, I just want to know how to activate it using a voice command, using the app itself. such as a voice-activated intent

Comment: It answers your need and if you had checked the link you'll find a section named "App Actions": https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview

Comment: oh i'm so sorry, didn't notice that. thank you so much!

Comment: just remember, accept the answer if is right for you.

Comment: Glad I could help! (: